# How to disable screensaver, sleep, lock, hibernate on windows 7 or using vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, power-management, screensaver

I don't have any idea if it is possible and how can I code it.

I have created an application that needs to run on a non-administrator account on windows 7. It won't run if the PC goes sleep/ locked/ hibernate/ on-screensaver. So, I want to disable them programmatically using vb.net 2010. Can any one help me?

By the way, I already tried to edit the power settings of the PC so it will never sleep/ hibernate, etc. But unfortunately, it keeps on sleeping after few hours. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Const SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE As Integer = 17

Private Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SystemParametersInfoA" (ByVal uAction As Integer, _
    ByVal uParam As Integer, ByRef lpvParam As Integer, _
    ByVal uWinIni As Integer) As Integer

Public Function SetScreenSaverActive(ByVal Active As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim Result As Integer = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE, CInt(Active), 0, 0)
    Return (Result > 0)

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since the account I am using is non-admin, I cannot access regedit. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479403/stop-the-screen-saver-and-hibernation-temporarily-in-vb-net)) can be used to inform the system that it is in use. For CD-burners and things like that you might want to use [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: by the way, do I need to put the code inside the timer sub? or is it called only once?

Comment: Not if you OR with ES_CONTINUOUS