# Keep Windows awake when a WPF application is running

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

Is there any way (short of manually doing so in the Windows settings each time I run it) to make a running `WPF` application prevent Windows from going to sleep/hibernating/etc. The application is just running a continuous loop every 10 seconds in a `BackgroundWorker`. I noticed when my machine auto-slept, it stopped my `BackgroundWorker`, and I'd like to keep it running indefinitely.

If its not possible purely in `WPF`, are there other ways?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`SetThreadExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function. More information is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480383/871910)

However, don't do that if you don't really have to, and *certainly* don't do that before getting the user's explicit consent. Your users will be pissed off when they realize their laptops die while your program is running. So warn them properly so they're not pissed off.

Comment: Hmm, am I missing something? Is there a reference I need for the SetThreadExecutionState method? What class is it in?

Comment: It's a native call, you need to use P/Invoke to call it. See the second link I provided.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed there is. Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/09/30/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep.aspx) for a sample with source.

Comment: How about an explanation instead of just a link.

Comment: This is a good example why you shouldn't just link to an external site... The link only says "This blog has moved to a new location and comments have been disabled.", original content has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

use powershell script to keep the PC awake infinitely:

```
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
for ($i = 1; $i -gt 0; $i++) {
Start-Sleep -Seconds 50
$myshell.sendkeys("{F15}")
}
```

save above as a blha.ps1 file and run it.

Comment: Even though your solution works (seemingly) this is not what has been asked for.